# Safe way to persist multiple clients data

Tags: django

I am currently developing a computer based test web app with Django, and I am trying to figure out the best way to persist the choices users make during the course of the test.

I want to persist the choices because they might leave the page due to a crash or something else and I want them to be able to resume from exactly where they stopped.

To implement this I chose saving to Django sessions with db backend which in turns save to the database and this will resolve to a very bad design because I don't want about 2000 users hitting my db every few seconds.

So my question is are there any other ways I can go about implementing this feature that I don't know of. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is being run on a browser, to be specific, if you are designing a progressive web application, you can make use of browser storage systems, such as `localstorage`, `indexed db`, `cookies`, etc ..

This way, you wouldn't need to send user's updated state back and forth to your backend and you can do the state update based on a specific condition or each `n` seconds/minutes.

Comment: sure in fact I use local storage for some aspect of the app but what I want is a browser independent storage so a user can resume their test anywhere anytime.

Comment: So I ended up saving to localStorage on every important state change, to db every n minutes and on resume, I simply compare the timestamp on localStorage vs user session and choose which to persist from.